# Array containing constructor is undefined js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to java, and I am having trouble calling the contents of an array that has constructor. I want to specifically call the contents in the array of type "omAttachment", "omText" etc.

here is the constructor and array:

```
function observeMessages(attachment, read, senderId, sent, text, type, userName){
  this.omAttachment = attachment;
  this.omRead = read; 
  this.omSenderId = senderId;
  this.omSent = sent;
  this.omText = text; 
  this.omType = type;
  this.omUserName = userName;
}

var messageHistoryArray = [];
```

I add contructor like so:

```
var newMessage = new observeMessages(obj.attachment, obj.read, obj.senderId, obj.sent, obj.text, obj.type, obj.userName);
      messageHistoryArray.push(newMessage);
```

When i try to print in console, it says that it is undefined:

```
console.log(messageHistoryArray[0]); /in js file
```

When i print like this in console (google chrome) i get the following:

```
console.log(messageHistoryArray); //in js file

//print out in chrome console
Array[0]
     0:observeMessages
     omAttachment:false
     omRead:"read"
     omSenderId:"randomSenderId"
     omSent:1479573310.904605
     omText:"random text stuff"
     omType:"type"
     omUserName:"userName"
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine! Even in your example it is not printing undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

Working Snippet (Is your code any different from this?):

```js
function observeMessages(attachment, read, senderId, sent, text, type, userName) {
  this.omAttachment = attachment;
  this.omRead = read;
  this.omSenderId = senderId;
  this.omSent = sent;
  this.omText = text;
  this.omType = type;
  this.omUserName = userName;
}

var messageHistoryArray = [];

var newMessage = new observeMessages("abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc");
messageHistoryArray.push(newMessage);
console.log(messageHistoryArray[0])
```

Comment: i had it running inside an init function...and thats why i think it was being a bit funky. took it out  and looks like its working fine now.. Thanks!